# Github Actions Composite Actions @ Branch

Tags: github-actions

In Github Actions composite actions, you must specify the branch where the composite action is located, e.g.,

```
- uses: /username/repo-name/.github/composite-actions@main
```

Is there a way to specify the current branch instead rather than hardcode `@main`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After checking further, it seems using the relative path works. For example:

```
- uses: ./.github/composite-actions
```

Comment: I don't think it works if the action in in a different repository or am I wrong?